# PHP only show text once in loop

Tags: php, string, loops

I have a webpage which is grabbing information from the string $details and looking for 'displayname' through search and displaying the results. This is LDAP Active Directory querying.

I need "$search .= "NameTitlePhoneMobileEmailDept\n";" to only show once a search has been completed. In it's current state, it repeats this line for every result. How can i make this line only show the once, up the top?

```
    // Address Book Search
    $search .= "<div class='border'>\n";
    $search .= '<form class="search-form-wrapper" method="GET">
                    <input type="text" name="q" id="search" placeholder="Search for Staff..." required>
                    <input type="submit" value="go" id="submit">
                </form><br><br>';


    if (count($staff)) {
    if (isset($_GET['q'])) {
        $query = rawurlencode( strip_tags($_GET['q']));
        $query = ucfirst($query);
        foreach ($staff as $key => $details) {
            if(substr_count($details['displayname'], $query)){
            $search .= "<table class='address_book'><tr><th>Name</th><th>Title</th><th>Phone</th><th>Mobile</th><th>Email</th><th>Dept</th></tr>\n";
            $search .= "<tr><td>{$details['displayname']}</td>\n";
            $search .= "<td>{$details['title']}</td>\n";
            $search .= "<td>{$details['telephonenumber']}</td>\n";
            $search .= "<td>{$details['mobile']}</td>\n";
            $search .= "<td><a href='mailto:{$details['mail']}'>{$details['mail']}</a></td>\n";
            $search .= "<td>{$details['department']}</td>\n";
            $search .= "</tr>\n";
            $search .= "</table>\n";
            }
        }       
    }

    }

    $search .= "</div><br>";

$layout->content($search);
```

Comment: **PHP != jQuery**.

Comment: Move the `<table ...` line to before the loop, and the `</table>` after the loop.

Comment: I need to only show while the loop is active. I don't want the text showing on the non-searched page.

Comment: then you could use a simple counter variable, ie. `$show = 0;`. If it is `0` you echo the line and increase to `1`. If not `0` you don't echo.

Comment: That would be unnecessary, If the `<table...` row was above the foreach loop it would still only fire when `if (isset($_GET['q']))` and instead only fire once. Also move the `</table>` below the closing bracket for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

> To get the Functionality that you want, you may have to move the line: `$search  .= "<table class='address_book'><tr><th>Name</th><th>Title</th><th>Phone</th><th>Mobile</th><th>Email</th><th>Dept</th></tr>\n"` outside of the loop (just before the loop begins). You only generate  the dynamic rows of the Table  within the Loop. The snippet below illustrates just how:

```
   <?php

        // Address Book Search
        $search  = "";
        $search .= "<div class='border'>\n";
        $search .= '<form class="search-form-wrapper" method="GET">
                        <input type="text" name="q" id="search" placeholder="Search for Staff..." required>
                        <input type="submit" value="go" id="submit">
                    </form><br><br>';


        if (count($staff)) {
            if (isset($_GET['q'])) {
                $search .= "<table class='address_book'><tr><th>Name</th><th>Title</th><th>Phone</th><th>Mobile</th><th>Email</th><th>Dept</th></tr>\n";
                $query   = rawurlencode( strip_tags($_GET['q']));
                $query   = ucfirst($query);
                foreach ($staff as $key => $details) {
                    if(substr_count($details['displayname'], $query)){
                        $search .= "<tr><td>{$details['displayname']}</td>\n";
                        $search .= "<td>{$details['title']}</td>\n";
                        $search .= "<td>{$details['telephonenumber']}</td>\n";
                        $search .= "<td>{$details['mobile']}</td>\n";
                        $search .= "<td><a href='mailto:{$details['mail']}'>{$details['mail']}</a></td>\n";
                        $search .= "<td>{$details['department']}</td>\n";
                        $search .= "</tr>\n";
                    }
                }
                $search .= "</table>\n";
            }   
        }

        $search .= "</div><br>";

        $layout->content($search);
```

Comment: How does this met the OP's `to only show once a search has been completed.`?

Comment: @Sean       What OP wants is to show the Table header once. In his code, those were within the Loop. This just moves out that header-section out from the Loop to only make  it display just once.

Comment: In you original version you had it outside the `if (isset($_GET['q']))` so it would have been printed before a search was done. Your edit corrected that.